# Killing an app that fails the License check

Tags: android

I've been implementing the Android market Licensing in my app and it looks like everything works.  At present, however, when the chec kfails, I'l displaying a Toast message and calling moveTaskToBack().

This is obviously not an acceptable way to close the app, since the user can simply open it again and carry on as before.

What would be the best way to actually kill the app after the Toast has displayed?

Answer (score 0):

call finish() from the main activity

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is there any way of telling when the Toast has disapeared before calling finish()? Otherwise, the Toast doesn't ever seem to die...

Comment: Nevermind - I changed to using an AlertDialog instead of a Toast